# Flying Vanaras in Ramayana times

Tags: ramayana, hanuman

In Ramayana among the Vanaras or Vana-naras ( = forest humans)  plavagas  (fly-jumpers) were a talented class; among them  were Hanuman, Sugriva, Angada and others.

Did they lose this faculty later on and how? Are there some monkeys or similar forest dwellers in the world anywhere that can fly long distances?

Nowadays we see wingless monkeys that jump from branch to branch of trees holding on to them using legs and hands with equal ease ( National Geographic Channel videos).